# Use third-party library in cocos2d-x ( esp. android)

Tags: c++, json, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I create my empty project in cocos2d-x 2.2 using multi-platform python script. and It create one folder per platform. [ Here my problem goes with Android]

After installing any requirments (1) , and adding my *.cpp files name in `Andorid.mk` (2), I produced an .apk as output and it works !

**Problem:**

for "json" parsing, I'm using [Jansson Library](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/). In "windows" I just add a `.lib` and project worked. but when I compile it for `android` (with ./build_native) it gave errors ( and it should of course). **But I don't have any idea about how and where to add .so( or .a ?) to make it works !**